# Действие при выбранном radio

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте, есть такая форма:

```
<form action="" method="post">
<ul>
<li><input type="radio" name="payment-id"> Банковским переводом</li>
<li><input type="radio" name="payment-id"> Наличными</li>   
<li><input type="radio" name="payment-id"> По безналичному расчету</li>
</ul>

<p>
<input type="submit">
</p>

</form>
```

Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку и выбранном `radio` выдавался `alert` с определенным текстом?

Comment: @Сергей Образцов, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

```
<input type="radio" name="payment-id" oncklick="alert('Определенный текст!');"> Банковским переводом</li>
```

и никакого jQuery, ради такой ерунды подгружать целый фреймворк - ...

Answer (score 1):

Если без JQuery - то можно так:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validate (f) {
        var r = f.elements["payment-id"],
            rc = false;

        for (var i = 0, max_i = r.length; i < max_i; i++) {
            if (r[i].checked) {
               alert( "Checked payment-id, value = " + r[i].value );
               // Раскомментировать здесь, если нужно за-субмитить форму
               // rc = true; 
               break;
            }
       }
       return rc;
    }
</script>
<form action="" method="post" onsubmit="return validate(this)">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <input type="radio" name="payment-id" value="1" />
            Банковским переводом
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="radio" name="payment-id" value="2" />
            Наличными
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="radio" name="payment-id" value="3" />
            По безналичному расчету
        </li>
    </ul>
    <p><input type="submit" /></p>
</form>
```

Посмотреть, как работает более правильный пример можно [здесь](http://jsfiddle.net/chernomyrdin/tk3bj/).

Answer (score -1):

Сделать

```
<input type="button" id="send">
```

И

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$('#send').click(function()
 {
  var value = $(":radio[name=payment-id]").filter(":checked").val();
  switch(value)
   {
    case radioOne {alert 'one!';}
    case radioTwo {alert 'two!';}
    case radioThree {alert 'three!';}
   }
 }
</script>
```

И, ещё, надо, чтобы radio были типа

```
<input type="radio" name="payment-id" value="one">
<input type="radio" name="payment-id" value="two">
```

И т.д.
Для этого нужен jQuery.

Comment: @uramer, ну да, так тоже можно, естественно, но мой метод можно применить, если jQuery всё равно используется, а ради этого одного - конечно зачем грузить jQuery.
Хотя нет, погодите, у вас будет выдаваться алерт при клике _на radio_, а надо при клике _на кнопку_. Тут уже менее удобно.

Comment: Тут не нужны ни jQuery и SizzleJS ни макароны, ни даже дополнительная(!) кнопка.